# React - error while collecting modules by webpack

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, frontend

Good day!

I'm a new in React and I try to create my first App. But I ran into a problem. When I'm collecting modules by webpack, I get an error:

```
$ webpack
Hash: 3eddecfb03179fe8aace
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 71ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.78 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./src/index.js 269 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: D:\Projects\FrontEnd\loftblog\src\index.js Unexpected token (4:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { render } from 'react-dom';
|
| render {
|   <div>
|     Hello react!
```

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

render {
  <div>
    Hello react!
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
};
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `render` function correctly:

```
render(
  <div>
    Hello react!
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

(Instead of `render { ... }`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the Babel configuration, either in webpack (in the `loaders` section) or the `.babelrc` file itself. You need to tell Babel to process your code and apply the `react` preset.

If you post your webpack.config.js and .babelrc we'll be able to point the specific missing part.

Otherwise you may want to take a look into the `create-react-app` package which is a great and official way to kickstart a React app.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: If it were babel it would have error-ed on the first import line.

Comment: I think the error is caused by the `<div>` which hints that your `.babelrc` config or webpack config, depending on where you're configuring Babel, is indeed wrong.

Comment: It was my second error. But I have been doing all step by step.

Comment: Oops you're right Omri, I completely missed the typo in the code. Nice catch by you ;)